# Wrong character output from I2C LCD with Arduino

Tags: arduino, i2c, lcd, teensy

I'm just trying to print a string onto an LCD display (SparkFun 20x4 SerLCD - RGB Backlight Qwiic). The address of the I²C device is 0x72. I'm using an Arduino Teensy to communicate with the LCD display.

```
Pin Connections: 
LCD - Arduino
GND - GND (pin 2)
RAW - 3.3V (pin 3)
SDA - A4 / SDA0 (pin 18)
SCL - A5 / SCL0 (pin 19)
```

```c
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
int LCD_columns=20;
int LCD_rows=4;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x72,LCD_columns,LCD_rows);  // Address, Columns, Rows

void setup(){
  Wire.setClock(10000);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("2");
}

void loop()
{
}
```

In the attached image `lcd.init()` just prints the characters up to the `11!!` and when the `lcd.print("2")` is used it printed the random characters and also the `11!!`. I'm not sure where to go from here, any help is greatly appreciated. [Image of LCD display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzLQ3.jpg)

Comment: You need other pictures to be shared, i.e. SCL/SDA signals from oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, the library LiquidCrystal_I2C.h was incompatible with the LCD I used. Finding the repository on the LCD website provided the correct information. The Wire.h library was all that is needed.